# "retrieval" without the notion of "putting it there first"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word which describes the act (noun) of "retrieving" something which has not "been put there" by me in the first place.

English is not my native language, so it could very well be that I'm just wrongly interpreting the "re-" in "retrieval" to imply the above described notion.

*Example*: If I were to watch a video from some on-demand service, would it be correct to call that process a "retrieval" of said video?

Comment: I think only programmers and geeks would use words like *retrieve, fetch, obtain* in the context of on-demand streamed online content.  Most people would ***access, get,*** or more likely, just ***watch*** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary definition (from [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=retrieve&title=21st))

> **retrieve** *verb* (***retrieved, retrieving***)
>   1. to get or bring something back again; to recover.
>   2. to rescue or save something • *retrieve the situation*.
>   3, to save (time).
>   4. to restore (honour or fortune).
>   5. to make good (a loss, error, etc).
>   6. *computing* to recover (information) from storage in a computer memory.
>   ...
>   **retrievable** *adj*. **retrieval** *noun*
>   1. the act or possibility of retrieving something or getting it back.
>   2. *computing* the extraction of data from a file.

As you will see from the definition, ***retrieve*** has the sense of 'getting something *back*' or '*recovering* something'.

So the item must have previously been in *your* possession or in the possession of "an associate" (e.g. friend, family, etc.).

If you buy something in a shop, you are not *retrieving* it, because it has never been in your possession (nor the possession of anyone known to you).

Likewise, if you download a video, you are also not *retrieving* it, because it has never been in your possession (nor the possession of anyone known to you).  But if you have previously downloaded it and you can then *retrieve* it from your disk.  If your friend has downloaded it, you might *retrieve* it from his disk - whether that would be legal is another question!

Comment: I see, so my initial assumption wasn't too far off. But, is there a  single world describing what I'm looking for?

Comment: The most generic *verb* I can think of would be "getting", but not a similar noun: there could be so many differnt things you are 'getting' and in so many different ways. For the video, I would simply say *a download*; for other things, different words would be more appropriate. (P.S. Don't I get an upvote?)

Comment: I sense the issue with the on-demand content service example, is at what point are you deemed to be in possession of the content? You can buy the right to view a work, but then never watch it, although you've still paid for it, while the company will consider their part of the deal completed by granting you access, which is the equivalent of taking possession. Hence the downloading of it, could then be considered the retrieving of something that is already in your possession.

Comment: @user48193 Yes.

Comment: @user48193 TrevorD I'll have to thank both of you. In the end, it seems, without context there simply is no general word to use.

Answer (score 6):

How about "fetching"?  One can fetch something from anywhere without having placed it there originally.

> Jack and Jill went up the hill
>
> To fetch a pail of water

Comment: "fetching" then being the noun? Like in "a fetching"?

Comment: Fetching is not the noun, no.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve something that you haven't placed there yourself. For example, older boys might well send a younger person to retrieve their football from the garden of a neighbour, when they are the ones who kicked it in there.

Comment: I added an example to the question, would your answer still apply?

Comment: It would depend on whether you had previously downloaded it, and then stored it, in which case you would be retrieving it from your storage device. I think the key thing is, a thing must have been in the possession of either yourself, or someone else, to be retrieved by you, or retrieved by someone else on your behalf.

Comment: Ok, so if the thing has never been in my possession but I'm allowed to have it (even if only for a period of time), I could still call it a retrieval? I'm sorry for being so pedantic, I'm just trying to get my head around it! ;)

Comment: No! - see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I've just been mulling over that very issue. It's a tricky one really as it depends on the perceived status of a download. Technically speaking, you could argue that the content provider is making something available to you to retrieve, but it's a question of whether anyone would understand the use of the term under those circumstances. The question appears to be: is a download a form of retrieval?

Answer (score 1):

*[Grab](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grab?s=t)*, *[take](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take)* (or *[take away](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+away?s=t)*), *[claim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/claim)*, *[use](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/use?s=t)*, and *[get](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get?s=t)* all come to mind.

For the video example, though, I think *[stream](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stream?s=t)*, *[view](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/view?s=t)*, *[watch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/watch?s=t)*, *[play](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/play?s=t)*, and *[download](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/download?s=t)* would seem more appropriate than retrieve.

Comment: Links with definitions, please. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Retrieve" comes from the French word "retrouver" ("re"-again + "trouver"-to find).  If you didn't leave the object there, you FIND it instead of retrieve it. There are many English words that are better understood if you speak French, which used to be the language of the English aristocracy. Latin and Greek are useful too!

Answer (score 0):

There are many words you could use in place of retrieve. Get, acquire, fetch, obtain (be given), or attain (get with effort), even procure or purchase if you are buying it.

Answer (score 0):

from m-w.com:

Definition of PICK

> transitive verb 1 : to pierce, penetrate, or break up with a pointed
>   instrument  2 a : to remove bit by bit  b : to remove covering or adhering matter from  3 a : to gather by plucking  **b : choose,
>   select**  c : to make (one's way)
>   slowly and carefully

E.g. "I let my wife pick out a video she thought she would enjoy, but she fell asleep after 15 minutes."

Comment: @Mari-LouA added example to match OP request for information.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "***Access***" . It is the best choice for the example quoted by you. You access something when you retrieve it without having put it there first.

Comment: The verb “access” doesn't have the connotation (desired by the questioner, IIUC) of getting the thing across a distance, bringing it to one's location. That is, “access” just implies the object stays where it is and doesn't appear at one's location.